# To get value from parsed json using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code  i am just parsing a value using json and set it to textbox and on onblur event i want to get the value of a json object.Please help me to do .

```
var Reg = JSON.parse(RegularExpression);
//RegularExpression contains [{"RegularExp":"text","ExpType":"abc"}]
<input type="text" onblur="Reg(Reg)" />

 function Reg(val) {
        alert('Reg');
        alert(val);it display[object object]  i want to get the values


    }
```

Comment: Don't name variable the same as function

Comment: @charlietfl sure and i want to get values on onblur event

Answer (score 0):

Working Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aAcg87hPsQBibnpzj3pU?p=preview)

Reg is a var and also a function so Reg(Reg) will pass Reg function as a parameter.

So first change the var name.

Second the JSON.parse(RegularExpression) retrun an object so you cant just get the values by printing the var you need to reach them like here:

```
var RegularExpression = " [{\"RegularExp\":\"text\",\"ExpType\":\"abc\"}]";
var regObject = JSON.parse(RegularExpression);

function Reg(val) {
  alert(val[0].RegularExp + '\n' + val[0].ExpType);
}
```

and the input element should be:

```
<input type="text" onblur="Reg(regObject)" />
```

Comment: it returns undefined